# the ouput of the buffer is messy

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is the scene:

a.js:

something new!

the code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var fileName = 'a.js'; 

fs.open(fileName, 'r', function (error, fd) {

    var buf = new Buffer(1024);

    fs.read(fd, buf, 0, buf.length, null, function (error, bytesRead, buffer) {

        console.log(buffer.toString());

        });     

    });
```

the output is messy.

So here is my questions:

1. why the output is messy rather the valid part.
2. how to just output the valid part.
3. the third parameter of the callback in the fs.read is just the second parameter of the fs.read function. Is that right?

Comment: your code seems to be right except the buffer.toString

Answer (score 0):

You should limit the length to print by buffer like given here [Nodejs buffer](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end)

1. The output is messy because buffer prints the entire memory address that you assign on this line

   ```
   var buf = new Buffer(1024);
   ```
2. To output the valid part just put the limitaion over `buffer.toString` method like this

   ```
   console.log(buffer.toString('utf-8' , 0 , bytesRead));
   ```
3. Yes it is in the right way.

Comment: If so. Something still remains considering. If I just want to output the part read this time and the offset is not zero, how can i get the part i am interested since the offset is not a parameter of the callback.

Comment: i think offset is the pointer from which point fs starts reading your file and if you sift the offset to a different value it will start reading file from that line and will give you the value of that part in callback

Comment: fs.read(fd, buffer, offset, length, position, callback). accoriding to the api, the position is where to start reading my file and the offset is where to writing to the buffer.

Comment: yes you are right i have also checked to put different values for offset but it doesn't work only null and 0 is working , let me check in the source of fs i will update you  when i got something